# PowerShell - TRUE or FALSE returned If username exists in ActiveDirectory

Tags: powershell

I am wanting to check if an AD username exists, when I run the below condition I receive an error 'Get-ADUser : Cannot find and object with identity' This is obviously due to the specific username not existing, however if the condition is false then I want to echo a response to the user.

```
  $username_value = "JSmith"

  IF (Get-AdUser $username_value)  {
       Run script.....
  }
  ELSE  {
       Write-Host "The username does not exist."

  }
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** The answer below is correct for nearly every PowerShell cmdlet, but *not* `Get-ADUser` which somehow ignores `-ErrorAction`. I'll leave it here for future reference. In the meantime, you can use the following instead:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -filter {sAMAccountName -eq $username_value}

if (!$user) {
  Write-Error "This username does not exist"
  exit # or return, whatever is appropriate
}
```

---

You can just suppress the error using the `-ErrorAction` parameter. The return value from the cmdlet should be `$null` in that case and thus coerce nicely to `$false`.

```
$user = Get-ADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $username_value

if (!$user) {
  Write-Error "This username does not exist"
  exit # or return, whatever is appropriate
}

# run script ...
```

Comment: -ErrorAction doesn't seem to run silently (Error is still being displayed in red. 'Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity 'JSmith'. The script works fine when it finds a username in AD, however still getting an error when it cannot find an existing username in AD.

Comment: I have tried using $user = Get-ADUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $username_value. "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Force'